# Manipulating Checkboxes

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I have a list of checkboxes that the user uses to show and hide objects.  Some of the check boxes automatically check other boxes, ie: a "Check All" button.

Unfortunately, whenever I click the box manually it will no longer respond to functional checking, ie: $("#myCheckBox").attr("checked",true) no longer works.

This is confusing me, what am I missing?  It is like when I click the checkbox jQuery can no longer see it.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the code you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "correct" way to set checkboxes and radio buttons as of jQuery 1.6 is `$('#myCheckBox').prop('checked',true)` -- or omit the second argument to get the value instead.

In older versions of jQuery, you'd set it like so: `$('#myCheckBox').attr('checked','checked')`

Answer (score 1):

Try upgrading to the latest version of jQuery and use `$("#myCheckBox").prop("checked", true)`. If this doesn't work, it would help if you posted a complete example which isn't working.

Comment: Thanks for the point-out to the upgrade, I had not noticed that.  In the process of making demo code of my problem, I could not replicate it with a simple example: meaning that I need to go back through what I have now and find the more complicated answer.  Since this worked!  Thanks for the help!

 $("#foobutton").click(function(){
  if ($("#foobox1").prop("checked")){
   $("#foobox1").prop("checked", false);
  }else{
   $("#foobox1").prop("checked", true);
  }
 });
 $("#foobox2").click(function(){
  $("#foobox1").prop("checked", true);
         $("#foobox2").prop("checked", true);
 });